# Is there a way to run SimplePing asynchronously on swift?

Tags: swift, ping, icmp

I've got my hands into creating an application which pings local IPs and stores whether the IP is reachable or not into a table. A problem is that I need to do this task async and the amount of threads should be easily editable from code. For example: if max number of threads is 10, then 10 functions "ping()" run at the same time with different IP addresses from the array. [PlainPing](https://github.com/naptics/PlainPing) seems like the way to go, but I can't manage to run pingers async, they seem to be stuck when ran this way. Any suggestions?

Here is some code: (it's an example of only 10 IPs being checked.)

```
var queue = OperationQueue()

@IBAction func startPing(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 10
        pings.removeAll()
        for i in 1...244 {
            let newIp = Ip(ip: "192.168.1.\(i)")
            pings.append(newIp)
        }
        for i in 1...10 {
            let operation = BlockOperation {
                self.ping(index: i)
            }
            queue.addOperation(operation)
        }
        pingButton.isEnabled = false
}

func ping(index: Int) {
        let ping = pings[index-1]
        print(ping.ip) //THIS WORKS and after that PlainPing isn't.
        PlainPing.ping(ping.ip, withTimeout: 3, completionBlock: { (timeElapsed:Double?, error:Error?) in
            if let latency = timeElapsed {
                print("\(ping) latency (ms): \(latency)")
            }
            if let error = error {
                print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
}
```

I've read that SimplePing does not work with GDC. What would be other solutions then?

Answer (score 0):

ok i actually failed to find a concurrently working pinger library so i did this using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire):

```
AF.request("http://\(ping.ip)").responseJSON { (response) in
            if (response.response) != nil {
                print("success")
                let result = Ip(ip: "\(ping.ip) REACHABLE")
                ips.append(result)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                print("error")
                let result = Ip(ip: "\(ping.ip) UNREACHABLE")
                ips.append(result)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
}
```

Which actually works for me. If the local ip i provide is not reachable, the response remains empty.